# AOP and DI: How to create an aspect-aware interfaced dependency-injected object?

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, aop, spring4d

I'd like to create an *aspect-aware interfaced dependency-injected object* through the means of the Spring/4D framework. My issue is, that I don't know how to combine both parts. The general idea is the following:

1. Create the aspect layer object and hold two interfaces to it: one to pass as the dependency to the object (`IAspect`) and one to weave in as aspect into the object (`IInterceptor`):

   ```
   Temp := TAspect.Create;
   Aspect := Temp as IAspect;
   Interceptor := Temp as IInterceptor;
   ```
2. Create the interfaced dependency-injected object:

   ```
   Instance := TInstance.Create(Aspect) {as IInstance};
   ```
3. Weave in the aspect:

   ```
   Result := TProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Instance, [Interceptor]);
   ```

To solve this, I think of registering a factory with a custom constructor along these lines:

```
Aspect := Resolve<IAspect>;
Interceptor := Aspect as IInterceptor;
Instance := InstanceFactory(Aspect); // InstanceFactory := Resolve<IInstanceFactory>;
Result := TProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Instance, [Interceptor]);
```

My issue is, how would I register this with the `Container: TContainer` from Spring?

---

**Example**: The program below behaves like I want and demonstrates through which aspect layers the `GetValue` call runs. The custom object creation hapens in the `$Region` in the main routine. How would I need to refactor this program to use the DI container from the Spring/4D framework, yet keep the custom construction of an aspect-aware object?

```
program Project1;

{$AppType Console}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Spring,
  Spring.Interception;

type
  IAspect = interface
    ['{AF8E19F6-176D-490E-A475-4682336CAB89}']
    function GetSetting: String;
    procedure SetSetting(const Value: String);

    property Setting: String read GetSetting write SetSetting;
  end;

  TAspect = class (TInterfacedObject, IInterceptor, IAspect)
  strict private
    FSetting: String;

    function GetSetting: String;
    procedure SetSetting(const Value: String);

    procedure Intercept(const Invocation: IInvocation);

  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

  IThingy = interface (IInvokable)
    function GetAspect: IAspect;
    function GetValue: String;
    procedure SetValue(const Value: String);

    property InstanceAspect: IAspect read GetAspect;
    property Value: String read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

  TThingy = class (TInterfacedObject, IThingy)
  strict private
    FInstanceAspect: IAspect;
    FClassAspect: IAspect;
    FValue: String;

    function GetAspect: IAspect;
    function GetValue: String;
    procedure SetValue(const Value: String);

  public
    constructor Create(const InstanceAspect, ClassAspect: IAspect);
  end;

{ TAspect }

constructor TAspect.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FSetting := ' intercepted by class aspect';
end;

function TAspect.GetSetting: String;
begin
  Result := FSetting;
end;

procedure TAspect.Intercept(
  const Invocation: IInvocation);
begin
  Invocation.Proceed;

  if Invocation.Method.Name = 'GetValue' then
    Invocation.Result := TValue.From<String>(Invocation.Result.AsString + FSetting);
end;

procedure TAspect.SetSetting(
  const Value: String);
begin
  FSetting := Value;
end;

{ TThingy }

constructor TThingy.Create(const InstanceAspect, ClassAspect: IAspect);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FInstanceAspect := InstanceAspect;
  FClassAspect := ClassAspect;
  FValue := 'Value';
end;

function TThingy.GetAspect: IAspect;
begin
  Result := FInstanceAspect;
end;

function TThingy.GetValue: String;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

procedure TThingy.SetValue(const Value: String);
begin
  FValue := Value;
end;

{ Main }

procedure Main;
var
  Temp: TInterfacedObject;
  ClassAspect: IAspect;
  ClassInterceptor: IInterceptor;
  InstanceAspect: IAspect;
  InstanceInterceptor: IInterceptor;
  Thingy1: IThingy;
  Thingy2: IThingy;
begin
  {$Region 'How to do this with the Spring DI container?'}
  Temp := TAspect.Create;
  ClassAspect := Temp as IAspect;
  ClassInterceptor := Temp as IInterceptor;

  Temp := TAspect.Create;
  InstanceAspect := Temp as IAspect;
  InstanceInterceptor := Temp as IInterceptor;
  Thingy1 := TThingy.Create(InstanceAspect, ClassAspect);
  Thingy1 := TProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Thingy1, [ClassInterceptor, InstanceInterceptor]);

  Temp := TAspect.Create;
  InstanceAspect := Temp as IAspect;
  InstanceInterceptor := Temp as IInterceptor;
  Thingy2 := TThingy.Create(InstanceAspect, ClassAspect);
  Thingy2 := TProxyGenerator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(Thingy2, [ClassInterceptor, InstanceInterceptor]);
  {$EndRegion}

  Thingy1.InstanceAspect.Setting := ' intercepted by instance aspect 1';
  Thingy2.InstanceAspect.Setting := ' intercepted by instance aspect 2';

  Thingy1.Value := 'Value 1';
  Thingy2.Value := 'Value 2';

  WriteLn(Format('Thingy1.Value: %s', [Thingy1.Value]));
  WriteLn(Format('Thingy2.Value: %s', [Thingy2.Value]));
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  if DebugHook <> 0 then
  begin
    WriteLn('Press enter...');
    ReadLn;
  end;
end.
```

Output:

```
Thingy1.Value: Value 1 intercepted by instance aspect 1 intercepted by class aspect
Thingy2.Value: Value 2 intercepted by instance aspect 2 intercepted by class aspect
Press enter...
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but here it how to setup the container to get the result you are looking for. What does not work yet is contextual injection (making decisions during the resolve process that are based on the currently built object graph) - this is something we are planning to implement in the future.

```
program Project1;

{$AppType Console}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Spring,
  Spring.Container,
  Spring.Interception;

type
  IThingy = interface (IInvokable)
    ['{FD337CC6-03EB-4384-A027-E993AB687BF0}']
    function GetValue: String;
    procedure SetValue(const Value: String);

    property Value: String read GetValue write SetValue;
  end;

  TThingy = class (TInterfacedObject, IThingy)
  strict private
    FValue: String;

    function GetValue: String;
    procedure SetValue(const Value: String);
  end;

{ TThingy }

function TThingy.GetValue: String;
begin
  Result := FValue;
end;

procedure TThingy.SetValue(const Value: String);
begin
  FValue := Value;
end;

type
  TClassInterceptor = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterceptor)
    procedure Intercept(const Invocation: IInvocation);
  end;

  TInstanceInterceptor = class(TInterfacedObject, IInterceptor)
  private
    class var InstanceCount: Integer;
    var FNo: Integer;
    procedure Intercept(const Invocation: IInvocation);
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

{ Main }

procedure Main;
var
  Thingy1: IThingy;
  Thingy2: IThingy;
begin
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TClassInterceptor,TClassInterceptor>.AsSingleton;
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TInstanceInterceptor>('instance');
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IThingy, TThingy>.InterceptedBy<TClassInterceptor>.InterceptedBy('instance');
  GlobalContainer.Build;

  Thingy1 := GlobalContainer.Resolve<IThingy>;
  Thingy2 := GlobalContainer.Resolve<IThingy>;

  Thingy1.Value := 'Value 1';
  Thingy2.Value := 'Value 2';

  WriteLn(Format('Thingy1.Value: %s', [Thingy1.Value]));
  WriteLn(Format('Thingy2.Value: %s', [Thingy2.Value]));
end;

procedure TClassInterceptor.Intercept(const Invocation: IInvocation);
begin
  Invocation.Proceed;

  if Invocation.Method.Name = 'GetValue' then
    Invocation.Result := TValue.From<String>(Invocation.Result.AsString + ' intercepted by class aspect');
end;

constructor TInstanceInterceptor.Create;
begin
  Inc(InstanceCount);
  FNo := InstanceCount;
end;

procedure TInstanceInterceptor.Intercept(const Invocation: IInvocation);
begin
  Invocation.Proceed;

  if Invocation.Method.Name = 'GetValue' then
    Invocation.Result := TValue.From<String>(Invocation.Result.AsString + ' intercepted by instance aspect ' + IntToStr(FNo));
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      WriteLn(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  if DebugHook <> 0 then
  begin
    WriteLn('Press enter...');
    ReadLn;
  end;
end.
```